# How to rotate or adjust a big table in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Here is my example:

````
---
title: "There is a reproductible example"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r table-simple, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, results='asis'}
require(pander)
panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
set.caption("My great data")
my.data <- " # replace the text below with your table data
Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement
Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement
Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement
Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement|Anticonstitutionnellement "

df <- read.delim(textConnection(my.data),header=FALSE,sep="|",strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- unname(as.list(df[1,])) # put headers on
df <- df[-1,] # remove first row
row.names(df)<-NULL
pander(df, style = 'rmarkdown')
```
````

In the final PDF outputs, Words overlap.

I use "kable", "table", "print"
Do you have an idea that the words do not overlap?

If the table is very huge, I want that the table rotate automatically in landscape format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the option:

```
    classoption: landscape
```

in your head section

```
---
title: "There is a reproductible example"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
```

This will produce a landscape version of the document.